# Why is appcfg.sh only downloading the last 100 lines of my logs

Tags: google-app-engine

I am attempting to download my google appengine logs using the appcfg.sh client  utility, but no matter what I do I only get (exactly) 100 log lines.  I have tried the --num_days specifying a few days or 0 as per the docs to retrieve all available but it has no effect.  My logs are not particularly large and the 100 lines result in a few hours of logs totaling about 40kB.  And of course if I view the logs in the web console I can see many weeks (or months) worth of logs just fine.

I've been trying variations on the following command:

```
appcfg.sh--num_days=0 --include_all -A <<my app name>> request_logs <<path to my app>> api_2017_04_10.log
```

and the output I get is:

```
Reading application configuration data...
Apr 10, 2017 1:12:41 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.IndexesXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed <<my app path>>/WEB-INF/datastore-indexes.xml


Beginning interaction for module <<my module name>>...
0% Beginning to retrieve log records...
25% Received 100 log records...
Success.
Cleaning up temporary files for module <<my module name>>...
```

Note that it always ends at "25%" and "100 log records"... and 100 lines is nowhere near 25% of the total I'd expect regardless.

Answer (score 0):

After a week of intermittently messing with the this and always getting that same result this evening I ran the exact same script again and to my surprise I got 400 lines of the logs instead of 100.  I ran it again immediately and it chugged along for several minutes all the while reporting "97%" finished but continuing to indicate thousands of additional lines of the logs.  However it was not actually writing any data to the log at that point (I think it wants to buffer all of the data)... So I backed it down to --num_days=7 and that appears to have worked.

I think the client or API just very buggy.